# How to make the browser not open in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I tried writing like this, however still the virtual browser opens.

```
from selenium import webdriver

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.headless = True
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
browser.get("https://www.youtube.com")
```

I have tried doing this with the Firefox browser as well, however with no success.

Answer (score 0):

The code you gave as such will not work for `firefox` because the `selenium` driver is different and you will need to following statement

`from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options`

For `google chrome`, try this

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Set Chrome options
c_opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
c_opts.add_argument('--headless')  
c_opts.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  #optional


#Now initialise the browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_opts)

# Navigate to the URL
url = 'https://www.youtube.com'
browser.get()
```

Hope this works for you